# Python WatchDog Missing Events (on_created ; directories)

Tags: python, events, directory, watchdog, subdirectory

I'm trying to use python watchdog library in order to watch a specified folder & subfolders for the creation of new folders (they have a particularity : ending of the name is ".D").

The trouble is that in order to watch the specified folder & subfolders, I put the `recursive = True` parameter while creating the `Observer`. But it doesn't see simultaneous folders.D creations. If I put the `recursive = False` parameter, it watches only the folder specified (not subfolders) but is able to see simultaneous creation of Folders.D.

Source Code :

```
import os
import sys
import time
import logging
import configparser
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import watchdog.events as we
from pathtools.path import absolute_path, parent_dir_path

def LectureINI(path):
    data = path.split('\\')
    data = data[-1]
    print(data)
    file_runstart = path + '\\runstart.txt'
    tps1 = time.clock()
    while os.path.isfile(file_runstart) == False:
        time.sleep(1)
        tps2 = time.clock()
        print(tps2-tps1)
        if (tps2-tps1) > 15:
            break
    try:
        file_runstart = open(file_runstart, 'r')
        lines = file_runstart.readlines()
        ilines = iter(lines)
        for i in ilines:
            if "Sample Name" in i:
                sample = i.split(' = ')
                sample = sample[-1]
                break
    except:
        sample = '<Sample Name non récupérable>'
    file_ini = path + '\\PRE_POST.INI'
    while os.path.isfile(file_ini) == False:
        time.sleep(1)
    cfg.read(file_ini)
    try:
        date = cfg['POSTRUN']['Date']
    except:
        date = '<Date non récupérable>'
    try:
        instr = cfg['POSTRUN']['Instrument Name']
    except:
        instr = '<Nom instrument non récupérable>'

    infos = date + '\t' + instr + '\t' + data + '\t' + sample
    return infos

class MonHandler(we.FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        my_path = event.src_path
        if my_path[-2:]== ".D" and not "$" in my_path:
            print('Détection DATA')
            fileinfo = LectureINI(my_path)
            logging.info("%s\t%s", my_path, fileinfo)

cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('C:\Windows\win.ini')
read_path = cfg['WatchData']['Path']
BASEDIR = read_path[:-1]
if read_path == None:
    BASEDIR == 'C:\\'

logging.basicConfig(filename='WatchData.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s\t%(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d\t%H:%M:%S')
event_handler = MonHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, BASEDIR, recursive = True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #CRTL+C to stop
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

If anyone know why, it would help a lot !

Comment: If you're unable to solve the issue, how about running _two_ threads/processes in tandem, one with and the other without `recursive`?

Comment: Why not but how would it work ? Don't know much about thread and how to use them !

Comment: You can read https://pymotw.com/2/threading/ and https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html (and as always, GIYF :-)